# change brackets in list python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out why my code gives me:

```
([20, 50, 80, 110], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1])
```

instead of:

```
[[20, 50, 80, 110], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

does anyone know how to change the brackets?

```
def get_col_contents_and_positions_(x,y):
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if y in range(len(x)):
            list1.append(x[i][y])
            list2.append(i)
            list3.append(y)
    return list1, list2, list3 

mat = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90],[100,110,120]]
print (get_col_contents_and_positions_(mat,1))
```

Comment: That just means you have a tuple, not a list. `return [list1, list2, list3]` will do what you want, but it's likely you can do what you want with a tuple anyway.

Comment: You have a tuple and not a list in your code - you're appending to a tuple. If you'd like a list instead of returning `list1, list2, list3` return `[list1, list2, list3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
return list1, list2, list3
```

Means "return a tuple containing these three lists". 
Tuples are also indicated by round brackets `()`. Lists are indicated by square brackets `[]`.
If you want to return a list instead of a tuple, you can use:

```
return [list1, list2, list3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `list1, list2, list3` is a tuple syntax, not a list syntax. Write `[list1, list2, list3]` to build an equivalent list.

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
return [list1, list2, list3]
```

to return a list. Writing:

```
return (list1, list2, list3)
```

will simply  return a tuple instead of a list. So use `[]` instead of `()`. Why? Tuples are identified by using `()` like this one:

```
(var1, var2, var3)
```

Lists however are identified with `[]` like this:

```
[var1, var2, var3]
```